# What UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key is linked to the M7 Processor?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-m7

My step counter app is using the core motion framework and the m7 processeor.

However, it was rejected by apple for this reason:

---

2.3 Details

We noticed your app requires functionality specific to iPhone devices, but the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the app's Info.plist does not reflect this requirement. This key prevents users from installing applications on unsupported devices.

Next Steps

Since your app requires step counting functionality utilizing the m7 processor, please configure the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to reflect the appropriate devices.

---

Is it the accelerometer key that I need to add to the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the info.plist or is there another key for the m7 processor?

I have added the key like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAuFo.png
Does it look correct?

Help is much appreciated!